# Get encrypted password for PostgreSQL login role

Tags: postgresql, ansible

Is there a way to fetch the encrypted password for a login roll from a PostgreSQL server?

To give some insight into my problem, I'm trying to manage the `postgres` user's password via Ansible. To do so, I would like to check the current value of the encrypted password (e.g. `'md5...'`) to see if it's current or not. If it is not, I would execute the appropriate `ALTER ROLL` command to update it.

I know I can use `pg_dumpall` to *see* the password, e.g:

```
$ pg_dumpall --roles-only
<snip>
CREATE ROLE postgres;
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH ... PASSWORD 'md5...';
```

But this doesn't seem like a very reliable way of doing so.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to read rolpassword field.

```
SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_authid
```

[**pg_authid**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/catalog-pg-authid.html)

> The catalog pg_authid contains information about database
>   authorization identifiers (roles). A role subsumes the concepts of
>   "users" and "groups". A user is essentially just a role with the
>   rolcanlogin flag set. Any role (with or without rolcanlogin) can have
>   other roles as members; see pg_auth_members.
>
> Since this catalog contains passwords, it must not be publicly
>   readable. pg_roles is a publicly readable view on pg_authid that
>   blanks out the password field.
>
> Chapter 19 contains detailed information about user and privilege
>   management.
>
> Because user identities are cluster-wide, pg_authid is shared across
>   all databases of a cluster: there is only one copy of pg_authid per
>   cluster, not one per database.

Comment: the passwords in `pg_authid`, when md5, are concatenated with the username before encrypthion, so comparing that to a bare password's md5 will not be useful. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-authid.html)

Comment: For the "postgres" user: `SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname='postgres';` Or for all, with the usernames: `SELECT rolname, rolpassword FROM pg_authid;`